# Can not leverage browser caching in codeigniter using htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using *chrome* audit , I found several problems with my page but i can not get rid of one red balloon saying **browser could not leverage cache**.

So i started searching , I found a solution saying append the following code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

In **codeigniter/system** i found an **httaccess** file saying **"deny from all"**, i overwrite that with the following code but i can not get my browser to leverage my static resources. Please tell me how to fix this ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked deep, it seem that in my configuration file overriding .htaccess was disabled , so i enabled it and it worked .